# How to provide fixed header in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, header

I am using create account page. I used header title.but the issue is, when i provide      input fields through scrolling and typing input,it works good without hididng the header. But when I click next in kepad, header is hidding. How to solve this?

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savecInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savecInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.account);
    setHeaderTitle(getString(R.string.create_account));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the header out of your scrollview like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        layout="@layout/footer" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/header" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This will cause the header to stay fixed even when the layout is scrolled upon opening the soft keyboard.